# Find few things in Apache Solr

Tags: java, solr

How can I find these things from Apache Solr. As I have several documents indexed into Apache Solr. I need to find these things--

```
Last_commit Time
Last_Optimize Time
Last_Replication Time
Index Size
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the details for the replication time and index size with the replication details.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/replication/?command=details
```

Response -

```
<str name="indexSize">192.07 MB</str>

<arr name="indexReplicatedAtList">
    <str>Thu Nov 10 09:01:44 EST 2011</str>
</arr>
```

Not sure, if there is a direct handle to get the last commit and optimize time through http.

Comment: Thanks for the information. And last commit time is last modified time or something else. As I can get the last modified date from luke request handler..

Comment: ,And `indexReplicatedAtList` is the replication time or `indexReplicatedAt` is the replication time